# Combine TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance and TableGenerator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

Is there a way to have a segment column value distinct for each child of an abstract entity containing the definition of ID with TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance in hibernate please ?

I have two entites extended from an asbtract entity as below :

```
@Entity
@GenericGenerator(name = "credentialIdGenerator",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator",
        parameters = {
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "value_column_name", value = "GEN_VALUE"),
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "segment_column_name", value = "GEN_NAME"),
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "table_name", value = "CORE_CREDENTIAL_ID_GEN"),
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "prefer_entity_table_as_segment_value", value = "true"),
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "pooled-lo"),
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "50000"),
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "100")})
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Credential implements Serializable {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "credentialIdGenerator")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_a")
public class EntityA extends Credential { ... }

@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_b")
public class EntityB extends Credential { ... }
```

The fact is the TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance strategy is the most suitable strategy for the current architecture of our DB, the fact is there is no way for now to create a new table Credential.
EntityA and EntityB are two existing tables with a lot of rows and I need Credential as entity (and not @MappedSuperClass) to still be able to have @OneToMany relationships.

The expected behaviour is to have distinct rows in my CORE_CREDENTIAL_ID_GEN for each entity, one for EntityA and another one for EntityB when I have to save a new of these two entities but the result is just one row with Credential as below :

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | GEN_NAME   | GEN_VALUE |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 | Credential |     50099 |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

So there is a way of configuration to have the expected behaviour one this generation id table ?

Thank you for your help

*(My DB environnment is MariaDB 10.3)*

Answer (score 1):

That's expected. If you want different id spaces you have to separate the entities i.e. remove the super class. What's the issue with `@OneToMany`? You can refer to both entities if you want through e.g.

```
@Column(name = "credential_fk")
Integer credentialFk;
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "credential_fk", insertable = false, updatable = false)
Set<Entity1> entity1;
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "credential_fk", insertable = false, updatable = false)
Set<Entity2> entity2;
```

Comment: The fact is my abstract entity is used in my core spring security logic and linked to roles with OneToMany relatioship and in ManyToOne to another entity. Moreover, depending on the spring project, this Credential entity is the EntityA or EntityB.

Assuming I'm doing what you said in my Role entity, there will be a moment when the EntityA and EntityB can have the same id and so the field credentailFk will be duplicated, do you understand what I mean ? (Sorry I'm french haha)

Comment: Hmm, you are right, but you would have this problem also when having a dedicated (overlapping) id space for each entity, so either you need 2 FKs do distinguish the two kinds anyway, or you stick to a single id space.

Comment: Yes, I agree, what's the best on your opinion ?

Comment: Just keep on using a single id space :)